# How to fix invalid literal for int() with base 10 python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on AI tic toe game code, it runs well but some times when I give input 9 it gives error "invalid literal for int() with base 10 python 3" or  "list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType".

```
def getPlayerMove(board):
    while  True:
        print('What is your next move? (1-9)')
        move = int(input())
        if move in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and isSpaceFree(board, move):
            mo=move
            break
        else:
            continue
            return mo

def isSpaceFree(board, move):
     # Return true if the passed move is free on the passed board.

    return board[move] == ' '

def makeMove(board, letter, move):
    #place letter on the board at move

    board[move] = letter
```

Comment: The code you are showing does nothing by itself, and none of the functions call each other. Can you please provide a reproducible code sample for the errors?

Comment: Take note that ``getPlayerMove`` will *always*  return ``None``. The sole ``return`` statement is not reachable.